# jQuery library doesn't import correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I installed a few libraries, like toastr. In `app.js` file I imported that:

```
import 'toastr/build/toastr.min.js';
```

and compiled as:

```
npm run dev
```

Of course, I included an app file into `app.blade` view.

I tried using this library:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        toastr.success('Have fun storming the castle!', 'Miracle Max Says')
    });
</script>
```

But I have this error in my console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

I know that I have included this script by `<script>` but I want to use `app.js`. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: The usage looks like you are accessing it outside the import, which means it's accessing `window.toastr`. Can you confirm that the import is correctly exposed on the `window` object?

Comment: This question is not PHP or Laravel. You can remove the tags as they are not relevant.